# How to write the condition in between some part of total content and single largest item's content in Linear Programming

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Am trying to solve an optimization problem with Python pulp. 
Following is my basic LP model.

```
prob = LpProblem("Minimizing cost", LpMinimize)
A = LpVariable("A", lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
B = LpVariable("B", lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
C = LpVariable("C", lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
prob += 1*A + 1.58*B + 2.98*C, "Objective function"
prob += 2*A + 4*B + 8*C >= content_requirement, "Content requirement"
prob += A+B+C <= 50
```

To this model, how can I add one more constraint to specify 45% of total content should be more than one largest item's content in the solution. Following are the few example cases.

```
    case1: Solver gives the solution A=5, B=0, C=0. (Here, A is the item with largest content as B and C are zeros).
           so the condition 45%(2*5 + 4*0 + 8*0) >= 2 should be true.
    case2: Solver gives the solution A=3, B=2, C=0. (Here, B is the item with largest content as C is zero).
           so the condition 45%(2*3 + 4*2 + 8*0) >= 4 should be true.
    case3: Solver gives the solution A=1, B=1, C=2. (Here, C is the item with largest content).
           so the condition 45%(2*1 + 4*1 + 8*2) >= 8 should be true.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the total content is given by 2*A + 4*B + 8*C and the content of item A by 2*A, it looks that you want to say:

```
 0.45 (coeff_A * A + coeff_B * B + coeff_C * C) >= max(coeff_A * A + coeff_B * B + coeff_C * C)
```

where A, B, C represent variables and coeff_A, coeff_B, coeff_C coefficients their coefficients in the content requirement constraint.
In such a case, it is enough to add a constraint per variable:

```
 0.45 (coeff_A * A + coeff_B * B + coeff_C * C) >= coeff_A * A
 0.45 (coeff_A * A + coeff_B * B + coeff_C * C) >= coeff_B * B
 0.45 (coeff_A * A + coeff_B * B + coeff_C * C) >= coeff_C * C
```

that with pulp becomes

```
 prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 2*A
 prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 4*B
 prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 8*C
```

Comment: 45% of total content should more than the ONE largest item's content. If you see case3 in the problem, even though C value is 2, I want to compare 45% of total content with one C item's content i.e 8.

Comment: Can we apply the If-else conditions in constraints?

Comment: It is possible but not easy to formulate this with extra binary variables. Looks to me like a strange condition. You may want to check if this is really what is needed.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, Il modify the requirements as follows, Can you pls have a look at it.
if C > 0,
     prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 8 (8 is C's content)
elif B > 0,
     prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 4 (4 is B's content)
elif A > 0,
      prob += 0.45 * (2*A + 4*B + 8*C) >= 2 (2 is A's content)

How can we write the constraints to these requirements with binary variables.

Comment: @PadmanabhamNooka This is easier to do but not completely trivial. Your teacher should be able to explain how to do this (it requires a bit more text that I can write here).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, Am a self learner and novice in LP. Can you please explain your approach here. Thanks in advance.